# How can I send this variable from django view to html using ajax on key up?

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I am making and app that send data in realtime to the user in the html and I want to update the paragraph tag every time the users releases a key.

My HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<p id="amount_word" class="amount_word" style="text-align:center">{{ amount_words }}</p>
</form>
```

My javascript ('texteditor' is a textarea that I have):

```
$("#texteditor").keyup(function(event){
           data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()};
           $.ajax({
                   type:'POST',
                   url:'/write/',
                   datatype: 'JSON',
                   data: data,
                   success: function(data) {
            console.log(data) // check out how data is structured
            $('.amount_word').contents()[0].textContent = data.amount_words
          }
          })
        })
```

My python view:

```
def write_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":

        def send_text():
            texteditor = request.POST['TextEntered']
            amount_words = "Amount of words: " + texteditor
            print(amount_words)
            texteditor = request.POST.get('TextEntered')
            if texteditor == 'NoneType':
                print("NoneType here")
            else:
                send_text()
            return JsonResponse({'amount_words': amount_words})
        return render(request, "write.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "write.html")
```

The template is write.html, and the URL is /write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it is working for me

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p id="amount_word" class="amount_word" style="text-align:center">amount:{{ amount_words }}</p>
    <input type="text" id="texteditor" >
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$("#texteditor").keyup(function(event){

           data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
           'TextEntered': $('#texteditor').val()};
           console.log("keyup = ", data);
           $.ajax({
                   type:'POST',
                   url:'/write/',
                   datatype: 'JSON',
                   data: data,
                   success: function(data) {
            console.log(data) // check out how data is structured
            $('.amount_word').contents()[0].textContent = data.amount_words
          }
          });
 });
```

in views

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def write_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":


            texteditor = request.POST['TextEntered']
            amount_words = "Amount of words: " + texteditor
            print(amount_words)
            texteditor = request.POST.get('TextEntered')
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'amount_words': amount_words}), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return render(request, "write.html")
```